# makebox and underbrace incompatible?

Tags: boxes

I tried to use `underbrace` within a formula within `makebox`, but that always produced an error.

For example `\makebox[100pc]{asdf $$\underbrace{3}$$}` produces the error while `\makebox[100pc]{asdf $$3$$}` works perfectly fine. Why do we get an error there? Is there an alternative to `makebox`?

Comment: Never use `$$` in LaTeX to begin with. Display math mode doesn't make any sense in a `\makebox` anyway, use a single `$`. By the way, it's quite likely that `px` means something very different from what you think.

Comment: What is wrong with using `$$`? (Yes the `px` should have been `pc`.)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) for some reasons why not using `$$` in LaTeX.

What happens in your case? You're typesetting a horizontal box and in this context `$$` just makes an *empty* math formula (the rule is explained in the TeXbook). Thus `\underbrace{3}` appears outside math mode and you get the error.

The same happens in `\makebox[100px]{asdf $$3$$}`: you get “asdf”, a space, an empty math formula, “3” and another empty math formula; however, `3` is not illegal in text mode and you get output without errors.

Display math mode makes no sense in the argument to `\makebox` anyway. Just use

```
\makebox[100pc]{asdf $\underbrace{3}$}
```

(you need quite a wide sheet of paper for this, because it's over 40 centimeters or 16 inches, even a bit wider than ISO A2 paper).